# Django - TypeError: put() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, postman

I am trying to upload a pdf file or a pickle file through an API made in Django using [FileUploadParser](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/).
However, when making the API call using postman using the put method, I get the following error, even using the right HTTP header:

`TypeError: put () missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'`

##### Here is how it looks my POSTMAN header and body:

[image: postman header]
[image: postman body]

##### views.py

[image: views.py]

##### urls.py

[image: urls.py]

Comment: Can you share what are those 10 request headers?

Answer (score 0):

I fix it changing the `class FileUploadView` to the code bellow, in order a filename it is not require in the parameters:

```py
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

    def put(self, request):
        file = request.data.get('file', None)

        if file is not None:
            return Response(f'File: {file.name} successfully uploaded!', status=HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(f'File not found!', status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add regular exp for the URL.

```
re_path(r'^upload/(?P<filename>[^/]+)$', FileUploadView.as_view())
```

Example::
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser